# Reed-Simon Vol. IV: Question regarding convergence of eigenvalues

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

I am reading through Chapter XIII.16 of Reed and Simon's *Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics IV: Analysis of Operators* about Schrödinger operators with periodic potentials. Since the topic is kind of advanced, I thought it is appropriate to post this here.

The question occurs in the proof Theorem XIII.89(d):

[image]

The part that is not so obvious to me is the last sentence. Why is $\tilde{E}$ an eigenvalue of $H(\epsilon)$? I know that if the resolvent of $H(\theta_n)$ converges in norm to the one of $H(\epsilon)$ this should be true by a general result, but I do not know whether this is true here or how one would derive this from the properties of $H(\theta)$.

Remark: It was already shown in part (a) of the theorem that the mapping $\theta \mapsto H(\theta)$ is real-analytic on $(0, \pi)$. I assume that this means that $\theta \mapsto \langle \phi, H(\theta) \psi \rangle$ for all $\phi, \psi$. I don't know if this is necessary for the above or if continuity suffices.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I think you can use a compactness argument to let the  normalized eigenvectors  $(u_n)$ converge. From the equation and the boundedness of $V$ you get the boundedness of $(u''_n)$ in the $L^2$ norm and then, up to a subsequence, $u_n \to u$ weakly in $H^2$ and strongly in $H^1$ and also the boundary conditions converge and $u$ is an eigenfunction of the limit operator.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I will definitely give that a try!